# Lag with alpha animation

Tags: android, xml, animation, alpha

I wrote simple animation for smoothly appear/disappear button:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="150%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
<alpha
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

But on device in processing my animation layout swaps. How can I process alpha animation without lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use [object animators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) (if api 11) or [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)